# does mysql use delimiters between columns?

Tags: mysql

As the title... does mysql use delimiters between columns?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Do you mean in the output, or in actual storage?  And why are you asking?

Comment: I mean in his way to store the data on hd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rough rule of thumb, storage engines will usually try to hold table records in as fixed a format as possible. As long as it knows the length of each field, it will mostly be a list of the total lengths of the fields for each row, plus additional bookkeeping data, like index links, FK links etc.

Large fields (`binary`, `text`, large `varchar` arrays) are held as pointers in the record itself, and the data is stored at the end of the file. Twice the indirection, but it's easier to increase the size on disk when needed (at the risk of wasting space). `varchar` specifically usually has a fixed, small buffer in the record in case it's small, and only uses the larger record at the end when the smaller one isn't sufficient.

But yes, you shouldn't need to worry about this. If you do then you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is entirely dependent on the storage engine used by the table in question. In general, you will go through MySQL itself to get access to your stored data.

If you specify `ENGINE = CSV` when creating the table, then MySQL will use [the CSV engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/csv-storage-engine.html), which does use delimiter-separated storage.

Answer (score 0):

Your question implies a textual storage of data in "flat files". MySQL is [Relational Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) which contains textual data, binary data, and data about the relationships between data. How the data is stored exactly is abstracted by the [Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engines.html) (InnoDB, MyISAM).

For the average user and programmer it is not as important *how* the data is stored so much as how it is accessed, how the tables are structured, and how the tables relate to one another. With MySQL you either issue SQL commands from a command-line interface, use a GUI database interface, or use an API from within the programming language of your choice.